# Basic Python Questions

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

The way I've done this is rather cumbersome. How would I be able to adjust the below code for the link to be amended with the country codes in the list, and load these json links, rather than unioning different dataframes.

Your help is much appreciated!

```
import urllib.request
import json
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

countries = ["nl", "us", "se"]

## load Dutch top episodes chart
with urllib.request.urlopen("https://podcastcharts.byspotify.com/api/charts/top_episodes?    region=nl") as url_NL:
dataFrameNL = json.load(url_NL)
print(dataFrameNL)

## load US top episodes chart
with urllib.request.urlopen("https://podcastcharts.byspotify.com/api/charts/top_episodes?region=us") as url_US:
dataFrameUS = json.load(url_US)
print(dataFrameUS)

# creating the dataframe 
## NL
dfNL = pd.json_normalize(dataFrameNL)
## US
dfUS = pd.json_normalize(dataFrameUS)

## add scraped_date
dfNL['scraped_date'] = pd.Timestamp.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
dfUS['scraped_date'] = pd.Timestamp.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

## add rank
dfNL["rank"] = dfNL.index + 1
dfUS["rank"] = dfNL.index + 1

## add country
dfNL['country'] = 'NL'
dfUS['country'] = 'US'

## concetenate 
union_dataframes = pd.concat([dfNL, dfUS])

## create file name with date output
file_name = 'mycsvfile' + str(datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')) + '.csv'

# converted a file to csv
union_dataframes.to_csv(file_name, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

I'm loading different datasets and concatenating them rather then using a loop function over a list.

Comment: If this code works, you should consider posting on our sister site [codereview.se] for suggestions to improve it. Be sure to check their guidelines before posting.

Comment: Hello, could you please rephrase your question title to make it more focused on your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create loop and processing each value of `country` for list of DataFrames, last outside loop join together by [`concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

countries = ['nl', 'us', 'se']
url_base = 'https://podcastcharts.byspotify.com/api/charts/top_episodes'
today = pd.Timestamp.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

dfs = []
for country in countries:
    # dynamic set country by f-string
    with urllib.request.urlopen(f'{url_base}?region={country}') as url:
        dataFrame = json.load(url)
    
    df = pd.json_normalize(dataFrame)
    
    # add scraped_date
    df['scraped_date'] = today
    
    # add rank
    df['rank'] = dfNL.index + 1
    
    # add country, dynamic generate uppercase country name
    df['country'] = country.upper()
    dfs.append(df)

# concatenate
union_dataframes = pd.concat(dfs)

# create file name with date output
file_path = Path(f'mycsvfile{today}.csv')

# converted a file to csv
union_dataframes.to_csv(file_path, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

EDIT:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

countries = ['nl', 'us', 'se']

url_base = 'podcastcharts.byspotify.com/api/'
today = pd.Timestamp.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

dfs = []
for country in countries:
    for category in categories:
        # dynamic set country by f-string
        with urllib.request.urlopen(f'{url_base}charts{category}?region={country}') as url:
            dataFrame = json.load(url)
        
        df = pd.json_normalize(dataFrame)
        
        # add scraped_date
        df['scraped_date'] = today
        
        # add rank
        df['rank'] = dfNL.index + 1
        
        # add country, dynamic generate uppercase country name
        df['country'] = country.upper()
        df['category'] = category
        dfs.append(df)
```

---

```
# concatenate
union_dataframes = pd.concat(dfs)

# create file name with date output
file_path = Path(f'mycsvfile{today}.csv')

# converted a file to csv
union_dataframes.to_csv(file_path, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Comment: I'm kinda stuck if I want to go a dimension further though. How would I amend this if I can insert both a category and a country code based on a list? 
https://podcastcharts.byspotify.com/api/charts/{category}?region=us

Comment: amazing, got it to work. Appreciate you!